# How to open language list page in android Programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intentservice

I have to open language selection page in android from application.
i am using below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.LanguageSettings");            
startActivity(intent);
```

But this is calling "language and input page" again i have to click on language tab to go inside and select language, so is there any way to open that language page directly.

Answer (score 3):

I found this:

```java
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS), 0);
```

This worked for me

Comment: If you don't need the result, you can just do `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS))`

Answer (score 1):

If language Tab is an activity than you can do by same way as above.

That you can check using following command :

`adb shell dumpsys activity`

This command show current activity name in activity stack. From this you can find name that you can pass in Intent to directly that start this activity.

Comment: yes correct, For that i am getting "com.android.settings.LanguageSettings.SubSettings", so i tried with same , but appplication is crashing, i think becuase there are so many subsettings for that so which 1 has to select.